# Domain Hosting, Editing MX Records for HTTP Only while retaining Email Hosting

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I am inexperienced with anything related to domain administration, so I am at a pretty big loss, but here is our problem.

This company has a situation where they own a domain through netsol.com, so they have full access to the domain.

However, they have email hosting through their ISP - the domain is forwarded to the ISP, and the mail system is all setup on that end.

They want to add a website, but the ISP offers very, very poor hosting packages that are EXTREMELY expensive and very cruddy (5 MB space on ASP.NET 1.0 for $100/mo)

The company is out in the middle of nowhere, so other ISPs are NOT an option. They want to purchase a hosting package from a better provider, but they do not want to lose their email configuration (over 300+ email accounts).

Is there a way to edit the settings on a domain so that they can keep their email forwarded to the ISP's servers, but change web hosting (http) to a different hosting package?

Forgive me but for privacy reasons I cannot give out any names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This belongs on serverfault.com

However, a quick answer is that they need to figure out who is running the DNS.  You can point your mail to one provider, web to another, and create all sorts of names that go elsewhere.

If network solutions is hosting the DNS (as they most likely are) then all the "company" has to do is figure out who they want to host the website.  Once they've started the account, the "company" can point the www entry to the web hosting provider.  Hosting providers are very good about walking you through this process.

There are literally hundreds of hosting providers out there, so finding a decent one should be simple.